# SSIS Script task without Visual Studio 2012

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm using VS2013 with SSDT installed. Added a Script Task but when I try to Edit the script it tries to open in VS2012, which I do not have a license for (trial expired). Is there a way around this?

Comment: I believe something is wrong with your installation. I have Visual Studio 2013 installed with SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence edition for SQL Server 2014. When I open a script task, it never attempts to open it in VS 2012. If your license has lapsed for 2012, why not uninstall it?

Comment: Strange. Thanks for the heads up @billinkc. I'll try uninstalling it.